# Spring Data JPA + Hibernate Marking methods as Transactional

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am using Spring data JPA's repository for my application. Currently I am using basic CRUD operations provided by default by spring data jpa repositories and for complex join queries, I am writing custom JPQL queries as follows:

```
public interface ContinentRepository extends JpaRepository<Continent, Long>
{
    @Query(value = "SELECT u FROM Continent u JOIN FETCH ... WHERE u.id = ?1")
    public List<Continent> findContinent(Long id);
}
```

In my Service class, I am autowiring this repository and performing DB operations.

```
@Service
public class MyService
{
    @Autowired
    public ContinentRepository cr;

    public void read()
    {
        var result1 = cr.findContinent(1);
        var result2 = cr.findContinent(2);
    }


    @Transactional
    public void write()
    {
        var c = new Continent();
        // setters
        c = cr.save(c);
    }
}
```

Currently I am just marking the `write()` as `org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional`.

1. Should I also mark `read()` method with `Transactional(readOnly = true)`? As it only performs read operations.
2. Should I also mark the `findContinent(Long id)` as Transactional(readOnly = true)? I read that all the default methods as marked as Transactional https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#transactions
3. In the repository interface, should I mark the Transactional annotation at the method level or at the interface level. (Also, I suspect most of the custom methods will be read only)
4. Is it good to have @Transactional at both Service and Repository layer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. Should I also mark read() method with Transactional(readOnly = true)? As it only performs read operations.

Not really necessary, however it might create some optimisations regarding cache memory consumption accordingly to this blog https://vladmihalcea.com/spring-read-only-transaction-hibernate-optimization/

> 2. Should I also mark the findContinent(Long id) as Transactional(readOnly = true)? I read that all the default methods as
>    marked as Transactional
>    https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#transactions

The same answer like in the first case

> 3. In the repository interface, should I mark the Transactional annotation at the method level or at the interface level. (Also, I
>    suspect most of the custom methods will be read only)

In general I added to the method level, because I have more control over the parameters like rollback

> 4. Is it good to have @Transactional at both Service and Repository layer?

I recommend you to have at the Service level because, there, you can update many tables (so you can use many repositories), and you want your entire update to be transactional.

Comment: That `@Transactional(readOnly = true)` is redundant is not strictly true. It depends on the isolation level. While it is indeed redundant for `READ COMMITED`, the behaviour *will* differ for `REPEATABLE READ` and higher isolation levels, where read locks are not immediately released

Comment: If I annotate Service class with Transactional and a method inside that service class with Transactional(but different properties as compared to class level Transactional annotation), then which annotation will be applied. Does Transactional annotation support overriding properties at method level?

Comment: Also, when one service method calls method from another service and both have propagation as `REQUIRED ` but other properties are different. For eg: Method with `@Transactional` in service A calls method with `@Transactional(readOnly=true)` in service B, then is a new transaction created in this case?

Comment: This article describes the priority order in which annotation will be applied https://www.baeldung.com/spring-transactional-propagation-isolation#2-how-to-use-transactional But I cannot find any such thing in spring docs.

Comment: @JavaLearner If you annotate a Service with `@Transactional` and inside you call a repository method annotated with `@Transactional`, then you need to specify the propagation `REQUIRED` to for the repo transaction annotation so that to join for an already existing transaction and to not create another one. However you should check if your database supports this (it should). In general, I'm not doing this because I call the repositories only in services and the repository classes are package protected so that to not be injected in classes located outside of their package.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Should I also mark read() method with Transactional(readOnly = true)? As it only performs read operations.

Yes. It is good practice, you will know immediately that this method doesn't change anything in database, and what is more important, you will disable some unintentional changes in database using this service method. If this method tries to do any update on DB exception will be thrown and rollback will be called.

> 2. Should I also mark the findContinent(Long id) as Transactional(readOnly = true)? I read that all the default methods as
>    marked as Transactional
>    https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#transactions

Depends how you are using it. If you are always calling this from @Sevice then no. I think that is common use case as fare as I know.

> 3. In the repository interface, should I mark the Transactional
>    annotation at the method level or at the interface level. (Also, I
>    suspect most of the custom methods will be read only)

Same as 2.

> 4. Is it good to have @Transactional at both Service and Repository
>    layer?

Same as 2.

Comment: Regarding #1, it depends on provider https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Transactional.html#readOnly--

Comment: If you use Spring Data and Hibernate it is true. I am talking from that experience and it is most used stack. For me it want be acceptable if implementation not interpret Read-Only. It is very important when you are working in bigger teams.